# How can i get all users of my application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

i need a list of my application users.
i use facebook C# sdk

Comment: As far as i know this isn't possible , best way would be to save users in a database who have authorized your application.

Comment: And offcourse remove the users when they remove you application ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should store your application users ids on your own...

Currently this isn't possible with API Facebook providing.

BTW,
Official Facebook C# SDK is [deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/624/) so you may want to work with [unofficial C# SDK hosted on Codeplex](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)